# Why is milk blue?

Tags: minhag, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, dairy, color

According to the "kosher color scheme" meat utensils are marked red, and dairy (milchig) is marked blue. Now, red for meat is quite understandable since meat is in fact red. But why should dairy be marked blue?
How/when did this custom become established, and is there any record of it (or similar color scheme associations) historically? Does anyone know any other variations of this tradition widespread in certain communities or families?

Comment: "How / when did this costum become established" Is it in fact established?

Comment: Puk chazi ma ama dvar

Comment: I know of a family in which red was used for milk and blue for meat. I agree with @DoubleAA.

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi Seeing some people doing something doesn't mean it's established. Traditionally, meat was left unmarked (the lack of mark is how you knew it was meat) and dairy was specifically marked https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A4%D7%98_%D7%93

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Do you know why they did it this way?

Comment: I've definitely worked in contexts where both milchigs and fleischigs were prepared where other colour schemes have been employed. This is also more of a הנהגה than a מנהג

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi Sorry - don't know.

Comment: Blue is one of more common color castes for human breast milk. This is associated with the generally lower fat  content of human milk. This same effect can be seen in skim milk and is called the Tyndall Effect. https://www.thoughtco.com/why-milk-is-white-606172

Comment: Given that most plates are white, I imagine white stickers would blend too much ‍♂️. Blue lids on milk bottles is likely why we have blue, but that's just a guess.

Comment: @RabbiKaii It's associated with it's source which is the "Lamed" from G-d's name (think אל דד ומי דד). That particular name is connected with Malchut which is associated with the color blue. If you have a copy of that book on Jewish Meditation by Aryeh Kaplan, he mentions it there (the color blue & Malchut).

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Jewish-Meditation-Practical-Aryeh-Kaplan/dp/0805210377

Comment: @YaacovDeane sounds like an amazing candidate for an answer!!

Comment: @RabbiKaii This is not in the category of "an answer". It's more like the belief that nothing happens by chance in the world. That many labels and identifiers for Chalavi turn out to be blue is not an accident. G-d runs the world. But I have never seen anything written about that color being required or suggested for identification.I can't believe this was asked. It must be a slow news day!

Comment: @YaacovDeane They labels don't "turn out" to be blue, it is an accepted convention

Comment: red meat...so red=fleishig (also maybe blood). Bleu cheese? Skim milk looks blue? Blue=cold, like cold milk as opposed to hot meat?

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi Please see my first comment. These examples of industry standard labels also suggest the Tyndall Effect. https://cdn2.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/16/51/milk-labels-vector-5091651.jpg

Comment: @rosends your hot/cold observation points out that Red and blue are often seen as opposites.

Comment: also, green is parve because vegetables. This leaves no other high contrast and clearly distinct colors. Yellow is hard to see and other colors might be confused with red or green I guess.

Comment: @Shmuel Do you refer to a non kosher kitchen? According to Google blue is for cooked foods, or alternitavely raw fish. Dairy is white

Comment: However....... blue is often also used for fish in the industrial food industry for cutting boards. There are different kinds of blue used. Dark blue for fish, light blue for bread etc...

Comment: @Shmuel If you're right that blue cutting boards for dairy is standard than that answers the question and its not specifically a kosher thing. But everything I see online says white = dairy. Is blue something you have seen in multiple kitchens?

Comment: I would like to point out (rectification) that in the industrial kitchen world, e.g. professional kitchens, [blue is used for fish](https://kha.com.au/news/colour-coded-cutting-boards/) according to HACCP-rulings. I have, however, seen cutting boards being blue and assigned to dairy. Why that is, no idea. But it is not endorsed by HACCP-rulings.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by variations, but the Ramma in Yoreh Deah 89:4 does mention the minhag to have two separate knives, one for dairy and one for meat, and to make a mark on the dairy knife. He adds a warning not to deviate from the minhag.

> כבר נהגו כל ישראל להיות להם שני סכינים ולרשום אחד מהם  שיהא לו היכר
> ונהגו לרשום של חלב ואין לשנות מנהג של ישראל:

Answer (score 2):

Although like other users have suggested this Minhag is not officially established, that is the case early on with most Minhagim. I think most can confirm that when these are separated by colored marks the color scheme is in fact red meat blue dairy.
I suggest that red was the obvious choice for meat and it’s opposite is generally blue so dairy adopted blue despite it having zero relevance to dairy.
It could’ve been accomplished with black/white with white resembling dairy but I think those are commonly the colors of kitchen utensils and would not be as easily distinguished.